# How do I implement "in" and "out" connections of this circuit on a breadboard?

Tags: schematics, breadboard, telephone

I am implementing this circuit on a breadboard. The problem is I don't understand how to implement IN2 and OUT2 which is connected to 330PF capacitor, as input and output can't be insert in the same terminal..How can I implement IN2 And OUT2 on breadboard

Here is the schematic of the circuit.
PS: This circuit is not for public use. I am implementing this for my school project..

[image]

Comment: Send photo. Add thin wires to IN & OUT terminals and insert them in breadboard. Even testing this on a public telephone network or on a phone in a private home that is connected to a public phone network renders you potentially liable for very severe penalties. Some countries are worse than others. If your country used to have a king with a name that sounded similar to yours I would be very very wary about using such a device in any way :-(.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon What kind of liabilities would there be if it was tested in a private home? How is that different from an automated method of recording the audio out of the earpiece?

Comment: @BBz - I said "... renders you potentially liable for very severe penalties ...". I think that is a good statement of what I believe the situation to be. This varies immensely with country. I do not know where Umer lives but his name suggests he *may* live in a country with among the very worst records for doing nasty things to people. Really. He is obviously extremely inexperienced and if he connects this to a POTS connected phone line there is a moderate chance he will damage something and a technician may call. It can go from there. I provide the warning. More I cannot do. ...

Comment: @RussellMcMahon Was just curious to know if there was specific legislation you were thinking of - thanks!

Comment: @BBz ...it may be that I am being massively melodramatic and OTT. That would be good. Knowing that there MAY be consequences of the worst sort allows Umer to make considered decisions. [[I travelled with friends in one of the most sophisticated (and expensive) European countries. We stayed the night somewhere convenient because it was midnight and we were dead on our feet and it did no harm. Really. At 4am "The Man" came. Polite courteous understanding. Have a good night. Left. I am assured by locals that the police are facist thugs and that they would have been arrested. You never know :-).]]

Comment: @BBz - ... specific legislations ... -> Look at his name and my comment. I understand that when rendition flights were (known to be) operating, this is the country you sent people when you wanted them dead at the end of the process. Really. They may care not at all about phone tapping. I really don't know. And MUCH has changed there very recently. But it may be another country. //  You also would not want to be found using it 'in fun' even in the US or UK. UK get extremely antsi about such things.

Comment: @Russell - probably true about the UK, and stuff like the [News International Phone Hacking Scandal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/News_International_phone_hacking_scandal) isn't likely to help to change views on such activities anytime soon... :-)

Answer (score 2):

On a breadboard the connections are as illustrated below:

[image: Breadboard connections]

As you can see, you have two long power rail lines at the top and bottom (red and black) and many 5 hole strips in the centre (blue lines)
All holes on each colour line are connected together.
In the diagram the resistor is connected to the power rail (red) and also to the LED (red circular thing), since it is plugged into the same strip as the LED. The LED is then connected to the bottom power rail (black).
To connect two wires together, simply plug them both into one of the 5 hole (blue) strips.

Here are a couple of links that go into more detail:
[Wiki breadboard page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadboard)
[Electrotech breadboard page](http://www.electro-tech-online.com/electronic-theory/54-breadboard.html)